# Verify matrix identity $A^tD-C^tB=I$ on certain hypotheses

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof

Given $n\times n$ real matrices $A,B,C,D$ such that:

- $AB^T$ and $CD^T$ are symmetric
- $AD^T-BC^T=I$

Prove that $A^TD-C^TB=I$

The solution I have come up with after a very long time is to consider:

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & -B \\
-C & D \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}
D^T & B^T \\
C^T & A^T \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
I & 0 \\
0 & I \end{array} \right)\rightarrow\left( \begin{array}{cc}
D^T & B^T \\
C^T & A^T \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & -B \\
-C & D \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
I & 0 \\
0 & I \end{array} \right)$$
then $D^TA-B^TC=I$.

However this solution is apparently tricky. I would love to have a more natural solution (which may be applied to other problems as well)

Comment: There is a property of the transpose that says $(A+B)^{\mathbb{T}} =A^{\mathbb{T}}+B^{\mathbb{T}}$ Seems like it could be useful?

Comment: @graydad it is useful, but insufficient on its own.  Note also that $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ah I see why that would ruin what I had planned. Now my gut is telling me we need to show that $AD^T$ and $BC^T$ must be symmetric. If that were true, then the two results we listed above would get us the result.

Comment: @graydad how so?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom eh... never mind, I was too overzealous. We're still in the same boat. I'll just exit this thread now.

Comment: I do not see any problem with the solution you give. It looks fine to me.

Comment: yeah but I think there may be a better solution which would give me more than solving only this problem :)

Comment: This is the standard proof. I'm not confident the "more natural" argument you are looking for is there to be found.

Comment: I think this is as good as it gets (and is very neat IMO).

Comment: I agree with Christian Remling, I have this exercise in my course and my professor solved this problem exactly in the same way..

Comment: @Prometheus: if you would simply undelete your answer, I would be happy to award you the bounty.\

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that this $2n\times 2n$ matrix, indeed, has a name: symplectic matrix.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix

It seems like this property is a special property of a broader kind of matrix.

Comment: The bounty is yours; consider it a reward for an interesting question