# Three equalities and one distinctness condition for four matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Are there matrices $A,B,C,D$ (in $M_n(K)$ for some $n$ and $K$) such
that

$$
AB=BA, \ CD=DC,\ AD-BC=I_n, \ DA-CB\neq I_n 
$$

It follows from what’s shown in that  [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921552/ask-for-alternative-solution)
that $A,B,C,D$ cannot all be symmetric matrices.

Comment: Random comment: this is really easy to arrange in infinite dimensions. Just choose $A$ and $D$ so that $AD = I$, but $DA \neq I$. Take $B = C = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $A=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1},\ B=I,\ C=-I$ and $D=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$. Note that $AD=0$ but $DA\ne0$.